# Proper way to sanitize user input to insert in a Python SQLite table?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am developing a Python application that accepts three arguments then stores them into a database. The first two ("userID", "username") are grabbed automatically, although malicious SQL injection may be present in a username. The last, "location", is a zip code or city provided by the user, but I am treating this as a potential attack vector as well.

This is bad code, for some reason it is not replacing characters, but I will attempt to research and rewrite.

Example, let's set a variable as an SQL injection attack:

```py
username = "'; select true; --" # or "location"
insert_data(userID, username, location)
```

```py
def insert_data(userID, username, location):
    # Sanitize SQL input. The database is small, but this is good security practice

    # userID - must be 18 characters and only numbers
    if not str(userID).isdecimal() and len(userID) is not 18:
        raise Exception

    # username -
    # Should probably limit the length of the username here to avoid SQL errors
    # Will eventually convert this replace process to a function and repeat for "location"
    sqlBadChars = [";", "'", "=", "\\\\"] # and probably more
    slist = list(username) # make a list of the orig username
    for badChar in sqlBadChars: # for each bad char in the array...
        for i,c in enumerate(slist, start=0): # for each char letter,char in the list...
                if str(slist[i]) == str(badChar): # check if the character indexed is in blacklist
                        slist[i] = ' ' # replace with a space

    usernameNew = ''.join(slist) # finally, join the processed list
```

I've read many articles here on StackOverflow, Google, OWASP even, but **I'm not exactly sure what are the best practices.**

I'm also not understanding how these examples work:
Both safe examples return `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error`

```py
# SAFE EXAMPLES. DO THIS!
cursor.execute("SELECT admin FROM users WHERE username = %s'", (username, ));
cursor.execute("SELECT admin FROM users WHERE username = %(username)s", {'username': username});

# BAD EXAMPLES. DON'T DO THIS!
cursor.execute("SELECT admin FROM users WHERE username = '" + username + "'");
cursor.execute("SELECT admin FROM users WHERE username = '%s'" % username);
cursor.execute("SELECT admin FROM users WHERE username = '{}'".format(username));
cursor.execute(f"SELECT admin FROM users WHERE username = '{username}'");
```

As far as I know, they do almost the same thing, I'm just not aware of the differences?

Comment: "usernameNew" is a local variable which stops existing when function exits. You should e. g. return it.

Comment: The "do this" examples are parameterized queries. The potentially dangerous strings are handled separately just as strings without interpreting them as SQL code. Sanitizing these regarding to SQL injection is unnecessary.

Comment: The first "do this" has an extras single quote at the end of the SQL statement.  Both "do this" examples use `%s` and %(username) as placeholders, but for sqlite the placeholders are `?` and `:username` respectively.